# ibus-mozc Japanese ime not show up in 18.04

Tags: ibus, mozc

[image: ime]

I have logout and re-login,  and even rebooted several times.
But the Mozc IME not show up.
The Ubuntu 18.04 is installed default with Chinese pinyin IME, I want to add a Japanese IME.
Is there some way to diagnose the problem? 
I have not find any logging message about mozc.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible solution

Try to resolve your question with [IBUS](https://github.com/ibus/ibus) IMF and [MOZC](https://github.com/google/mozc) IME by:

```
sudo apt install ibus ibus-mozc mozc-utils-gui
```

(Let me know if this worked).

## Alternative solutions:

Others japanese IMEs to substitute MOZC are:

- [Anthy](https://osdn.net/projects/anthy/): `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`.
- [KKC](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-kkc): `sudo apt install ibus-kkc`.
- [SKK](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-skk): `sudo apt install ibus-skk`.

And to substitute IBUS as an input method framework (IMF) can be:

- [Fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org): `sudo apt install fcitx`.

  - you will need to install all japanese IMEs again, like:

    - `sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`.
    - `sudo apt install fictx-kkc`.
    - `sudo apt install fictx-skk`.

A list of IMF can be found in [List of input methods for Unix platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_Unix_platforms) and [Linux input method framework brief summary](https://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2011/01/15/linux-input-method-brief-summary/).